# limit of n-th root of polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

How does one show that the limit of
$$(p(n))^{1/n}$$
where $p(x)$ is any polynomial, is equal to one? I am trying to use the squeeze theorem but have no upper bound.

Comment: what kind of polynomial is given?

Comment: its degree is arbitrary, and it takes values over the reals.

Comment: What if $p(n)$ is negative? How do you define the $n$-th root?

Comment: It should not be the zero polynomial, however.

Comment: Is $p(n)$ is the ordinary partition function ? This is also true.

Answer (score 2):

If $m>\deg p$, then $p(x)<x^m$ for $x$ large enough. Therefore we have as upper bound $n^{m/n}$ for almost all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}L &= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (p(n))^\frac1n
\\\ln L &= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(p(n))}{n}
\\&= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{p'(n)}{p(n)}
\\&= 0
\\\therefore L = 1
\end{align}$$
2nd to 3rd step follows from L'Hospital's rule. 3rd to 4th step follows from the fact that derivative of a polynomial is always less than original polynomial by $1$ or, if $p(n)$ is constant, then $p'(n) = 0$ (assuming polynomial is not $p(n) = 0$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Factor out $x^d$ from $p(x)$, where $d=\deg(p(x))$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p(x) = b x^m + a_{m-1} x^{m-1} + \cdots + a_0$ with $b > 0$ then we have $$(p(n))^{1/n} = n^{m/n} \left( b + a_{m-1}n^{-1} + \cdots + a_0 n^{-m}\right)^{1/n}$$

As $n \to \infty$, the term inside the parenthesis converges to $b$. Note that $b^{1/n} \to 1$.

Now in order to evaluate $n^{m/n}$ we take the logarithm to see that the convergence is equivalent to the convergence of $\frac{m\ln(n)}{n}$. This can be seen to go to zero by l'Hopital's rule. Thus $n^{m/n} \to 1$. And we have our limit.