# Find the limit of $\sqrt[n]{n^2+2n+3}$ using L'Hôpitals rule.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Using the squeeze theorem $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\sqrt[n]{n^2+2n+3}) = 1$:

$\sqrt[n]{3} \le \sqrt[n]{n^2+2n+3} \le \sqrt[n]{n}^2 \cdot \sqrt[n]{n} \cdot \sqrt[n]{2} \cdot \sqrt[n]{3}$

Now I'd like to see whether I could also use L'Hôpital here, but I can't figure how that'd work.

I've found one similar question with an answer that I don't understand (first one), that may help: [limit of n-th root of polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971788/limit-of-n-th-root-of-polynomial)

Comment: is $n$ here a natural number?

Comment: What about [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/971808/296602) do you not understand? If you're uncomfortable writing $p(n)$ for an arbitrary polynomial, write out your particular one instead.

Comment: Yes @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner

Comment: +1 for the beautiful squeezing.  Always love the simple ones.

Comment: It's a little easier to use $n^2+2n+1<3n^2$ for large $n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: write your term in the form
$$\exp\left(\frac{\ln(n^2+2n+3)}{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $a_n>0$ for simplicity, we have
$$
\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
when both limits exist.

For $a_n = n^2+2n+3$ we have
$$
\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1
$$

Although this proof does not use L'Hôpital, it uses simpler results.

Comment: (use L'H on the ratio test so that you may properly answer the question)

Comment: How do you know the left limit does exist?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $X = (n^2 + 2n +3)^{1/n}$, $y = \ln(X) = \frac{\ln(n^2+2n+3)}{n}$.
Apply L'Hospital rule to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y = 0$. Consequently, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x = e^0 =1$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that to apply the L'Hospital rule you must have a rational function (you can take log or express as an exponent of $e$ given in previous answers). However, not always L'Hospital rule is efficient. It is easier to use comparison. You have already noted:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n^2}=1.$$
Now note:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n^2+2n+3}}{\sqrt[n]{n^2}}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$$
Hence the original limit is also $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\sqrt[n]{n}
\to 1$,
$\sqrt[n]{n^m}
=(\sqrt[n]{n})^m
\to 1$
for any $m$ > 0$.

Therefore
$\sqrt[n]{|P(n)|}
\to 1$
for any polynomial
$P(n)$.